# Need to take existing program and break off calculations into functions

Tags: c, function, loops, average

I have an existing a program that finds the highest, lowest, and average of user input numbers. However not I am trying to take those calculations and put them into individual functions. My problem is that I do not understand how to take these calculations that share variables, among other things, and put them into their own separate functions. Below is my code, in comments at the bottom is what I tried and failed at.

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int grades [100]; /*variables defining the array, the iterator, and input; which lets us take the input and validate before passing to the array*/
int i = 0;
int small, big, input;

printf("Enter a series of grades. When done, enter any number above 100.\n\n");

while (i <= 100) { //while loop to set maximum for array
    printf("Enter grade:");

    if (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
        if (input >= 0 && input <=100) {  //validate and impose constraints on grade values
            grades[i] = input; //if good, add to array
            i++;
            }
        else {
            printf("\n\nExiting entry.\n");
            printf("\n\nGrades entered:\n\n");
            break; //exiting loop
            }
        }
    }
int x, y;


big = small = grades[0];
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {   
    if (grades[y] > big) {  
        big = grades[y];
        }
    else if (grades[y] < small) {   
        small = grades[y];
        }
    }
int sum = 0, avg = 0;
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {   
    sum += grades[y];
    }
avg = (double) sum / i;     //formula for determining average
printf("Highest number : %d\n", big);
printf("Smallest number: %d\n", small);
printf("Average: %d\n", avg);



return 0;
}
```

failure code:

```
int x, y;

for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    printf("Grade: %d\n", grades[x]);  //print array
   }
big = small = grades[0];
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {   //for loop
    large(grades,y);
    smallest(grades,y);
    }
int sum = 0, avg = 0;
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {   //for loop for determining sum of grades
    sum += grades[y];
    }
avg = (double) sum / i;     //formula for determining average
printf("Highest number : %d\n", big);
printf("Smallest number: %d\n", small);
printf("Average: %d\n", avg);



    return 0;
}

void large(int grades[], int y);
void smallest(int grades[], int y);
```

Comment: Type of parameters passed and there is use is not correct , for example `grades` is `int` , so `grades[y]` will cause error .

Answer (score 1):

While other answers recommend use of a *global* to make the `grades` array available in functions called from `main`, the generally accepted manner to make a value available to a function is to *pass the value (or pointer to the value)* as a *parameter* to the function. You should *avoid* the use of *global* variables, unless they are absolutely necessary (a situation you are unlikely to encounter when you begin learning C).

When you pass a parameter to a function, the function will receive a *copy*. If you pass a value such as an integer or float, the function will operate on a copy of the value and the changes will *not* be visible back in the calling function unless the value is *returned* and *assigned*.

When you pass a *pointer* as a parameter, the function still receives a copy, but the address pointed to by the copy is the very same address held by the original back in the calling function (`main` here). Therefore, any changes to the value pointed to is immediately visible back in the calling function. That is a synopsis of what you will hear as *pass by value* or *pass by reference* (even though both are actually pass by reference)

In your case, you fill an array of integer values (`grades`) that you would like to iterate over to find the `max/min` values along with the `average`. You would like this to be done in one or more functions. Splitting the functions into a `maxmin` function and an `average` function will provide examples of passing a pointer to a value and having the changes visible back in `main` (in the case of `maxmin`) and in returning and assigning a value (in the case of `average`)

To begin, lets look at a simple function to find the maximum and minimum values in `grades`. You will need to pass the array `grades` (you actually pass a pointer to grades), you need to pass the number of values in the `grades` array, and then, to make changes to the values of `max` and `min` available in `main`, you will pass pointers to `max` and `min` as parameters. e.g.:

```
void maxmin (int *arr, int n, int *max, int *min)
{
    int i;

    if (!arr || !max || !min) return;   /* validate pointers  */
    *max = INT_MIN, *min = INT_MAX;     /* initialize max/min */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* update max/min pointers */
        if (arr[i] > *max) *max = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < *min) *min = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Above, you simply want to initialize the values of `max` and `min` sufficiently low/high so that all max/min values are recorded. (e.g. if your values were `-100 to 10` and you initialized both to `0`, your max would never change)

For your average, you will pass `grades` and the number of values the same way, but here you will `return` the value for `average` from the function. You must assign the return to a value back in `main` for that value to be visible.

**note:** a function may return a value of its type, but it *cannot* return a pointer to a static object declared within the function. Why? because the values reside on the function stack which is destroyed when the function returns. Only the return *value* is preserved for the caller (worry more about this later). For your average, you could do:

```
float average (int *arr, int n)
{
    int i, sum = 0;

    if (!arr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "average() error: invalid array.\n");
        return -1.0;                    /* validate pointer */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)            /* compute average  */
        sum += arr[i];

    return (float)sum / n;
}
```

Now putting all the pieces together in a short example (and noting end of input is generally indicated by a manually generated `EOF` which is <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze) you could do something like the following (while still allowing any value over 100 to cause return)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

enum { MAXG = 100 };

void maxmin (int *arr, int n, int *max, int *min);
float average (int *arr, int n);

int main (void) {

    int grades[MAXG] = {0}, i, idx = 0, input, max, min;
    float avg = 0.0;

    printf ("Enter a series of grades. [ctrl+d] when done:\n\n");

    while (idx < MAXG && printf ("grade[%3d]: ", idx) && 
        scanf ("%d", &input) == 1 && 0 <= input && input <= 100)
        grades[idx++] = input;

    maxmin (grades, idx, &max, &min);       /* compute max/min */
    if ((avg = average (grades, idx)) < 0)  /* compute average */
        return 1;

    printf ("\nThe grades entered were:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" grades[%3d] : %d\n", i, grades[i]);

    printf ("\n  maximum : %d\n  minimum : %d\n  average : %.2f\n\n",
            max, min, avg);

    return 0;
}

void maxmin (int *arr, int n, int *max, int *min)
{
    int i;

    if (!arr || !max || !min) return;   /* validate pointers  */
    *max = INT_MIN, *min = INT_MAX;     /* initialize max/min */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* update max/min pointers */
        if (arr[i] > *max) *max = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < *min) *min = arr[i];
    }
}

float average (int *arr, int n)
{
    int i, sum = 0;

    if (!arr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "average() error: invalid array.\n");
        return -1.0;                    /* validate pointer */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)            /* compute average  */
        sum += arr[i];

    return (float)sum / n;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/grades1 <dat/grades.txt
Enter a series of grades. [ctrl+d] when done:

<snip entry>

The grades entered were:

 grades[  0] : 80
 grades[  1] : 97
 grades[  2] : 72
 grades[  3] : 78
 grades[  4] : 94
 grades[  5] : 91
 grades[  6] : 78
 grades[  7] : 94
 grades[  8] : 89
 grades[  9] : 72

  maximum : 97
  minimum : 72
  average : 84.50
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions, and remember *global* only when absolutely necessary as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple problems here
you do not align you call function syntax with your function prototype
and your are not passing the grades array correctly as a function parameter
try

```
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {   //for loop
largest(grades, y);
smallest(grades, y);
}
```

with the functions defined:

```
void largest(int grades[], int y);
void smallest(int grades[], int y)
```

Thus being said, in term of performance you can compute min, max, and average on the fly to avoid multiple loop

Comment: Testing this it gives me various warnings and errors. warning: conflicting types for `large` and same error for `small`. Additionally errors for undefined reference to `large`, same for small. Then gives exit status error. I am sure I am doing something dumb, I modified the code above to match what I am interpreting for you.

Comment: this is maybe because you are using 2 distincts files no? In that case you need to ensure your 2nd file can see the variables (declared as global in the 1st file, by adding an extern int small, large, and so on

Answer (score 0):

As @Cherubim Anand already said: the problem is the scope of `grades`, you can make the variable global, as @Cherubim Anand already proposed or send it as an argument to the function.

```
int largest(int *grades)
{
   int i,big;
   big = grades[0];
   for (i = 1;grades[i] != -1;i++) {
      if(grades[i] > big){
          big = grades[i];
      }
   }
   return big;
}
```

And call it via

```
big = largest(grades);
```

Another problem: If the input is not a digit, the while-loop does not stop anymore because `i` is only incremented if the input is a digit.

The exact method is more or less a matter of taste, here is mine:

```
  puts("Enter a series of grades between 0 (zero) and 100 (one hundred).");
  puts("When done, enter 'done'.");
  while (i <= 100) {
    printf("Enter grade:");
    if (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
      // if the number is in the right range: keep it
      if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
         grades[i] = input;
         i++;
      } else {
      // if not: print a hint
         printf("\nGrades are between 0 (zero) and 100 (one hundred).\n");
      }
    } else { 
        // anything else, including the string "done", ends the sampling
        grades[i] = -1;
        printf("\n\nExiting entry.\n");
        printf("\n\nGrades entered:\n\n");
        break;
    }
  }
```

BTW: You should make it a habit to end `main()` with `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` instead of just returning 0 (zero) and with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in case of a fatal error. It is not necessary for such simple things like your example but is useful later. You might take a look at `exit(3)` for more details.